# Can I get AuthorRetrieval data since a specific year?

Tags: pybliometrics

I tried to use this format but it returns data from all the years:

AuthorRetrieval(author_id, refresh=True, kwds='PUBYEAR IS 2022 OR PUBYEAR IS 2021 OR PUBYEAR IS 2020 OR PUBYEAR IS 2019 OR PUBYEAR IS 2018')

To be more specific to my problem, I am trying to get the number of documents that have cited(cited by) excluding the self-cited documents of the past five years.

For the citations I used the parameters start, end(CitationOverview), but I cant find something for the number of cited-by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is unfortunately not possible. The Author Retrieval API returns only the current state - just as if you were looking at an Author profile on scopus.com.

The reason why your `kwds` parameter is ignored is because it's not a valid keyword. It's not made for a Scopus query string. See https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/args-and-kwargs for an overview of what the parameter does.

Your only option is to reconstruct author values from her publications. You can get them with the `ScopusSearch()` class.

I'd recommend to use a query like "AU-ID(123466)" and then extract the documents based on their publication year. This way it's much more likely that you can re-use the cached results.